# If array contains any data

Tags: php

I have these bits here that will display a google map link for me.  How can I wrap this in some sort of if statemnt that will check to see if there is ANY data in `$event['where']`. I don't want the link to display when there is no data.

```
<a title="See on Map" target="_blank" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=<?php echo $event['where']; ?>">See on map</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php if(!empty($event)){ ?> <a title="See on Map" target="_blank" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=<?php echo $event['where']; ?>">See on map</a> <?php } ?>
```

Comment: I put together something very similar to this when I saw the !empty bits from the other replies. I used a single PHP open and close tag at the begging and end then separated my echos with semicolons. Works Great!  Thank you.

Comment: @granttoth Remember to check the "Mark as Answer" for the answer that you feel [most] sufficiently answered your question ;)

Comment: Thanks Shredder. I had just assumed this was done based off the most votes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php echo (!empty($event['where'])) ? $event['where'] : ""; ?>
```

Comment: This would throw a `Notice` if the `where` element did not exist.

Comment: I don't think that is true - "empty() is the opposite of (boolean) var, except that no warning is generated when the variable is not set." from http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: `empty()` does not throw a notice if the value doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

The following will not show the link if `$event['where']` is not set, is null, is blank (`""`), is `false` or is `0` - I think it is what you want:

```
<?php
if (!empty($event['where'])) {
  ?>
  <a title="See on Map" target="_blank" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=<?php echo $event['where']; ?>">See on map</a>
  <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Why deal with the multi-line mess?

Comment: Yours doesn't do what is asked - for example it doesn't remove the link, only the href.

Comment: Was the issue the missing `?>`?

Answer (score 1):

Well `isset()` will determine if a variable/object is set and is not null

```
if(isset($event['where'])){
//...
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: `isset()` is not very good on arrays - `array_key_exists()` is better.

Comment: I see it used on arrays all the time, especially on `$_POST[]`

Comment: It's not relevant to this question, but `isset()`, when called on an array element, erroneously returns `false` if the array has an entry that has value `NULL`. `array_key_exists()` does not - it only returns `false` if the array key doesn't exist.

Comment: @BenjieGillam That is totally bogus, and I'd appreciate it if you removed your downvote

Comment: It's not bogus, it's referenced in the documentation for isset that you linked to.

Comment: @BenjieGillam If you are referring to the "multiple parameters" statement in the link, that is only with *multiple parameters*. Please test the following code:  
`$myArr = array("hello", "this", null, "was", "for testing");  
if(isset($myArr[4]))  
 echo "ele: " . $myArr[4] . "<br/>";  
else   
 echo "error<br/>";`

Comment: If you correctly access `$myArr[2]` instead of `$myArr[4]` in your code above (for the `null`), you will get 'error' :)

Comment: @BenjieGillam Well no crap. That is not erroneous. An element that is `null` *should* return false, and is the desired effect in php and in the OP's situation.